# Jumper EZBook S5 No Audio on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: sound, alsa, 21.10

I have tried to install Ubuntu on EZbook S5 from Jumper. I tried once to install Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS  and after it Ubuntu 21.10. In both cases there is no sound at all. In settings I can see only the Dummy Output as Output device. Furthermore it shows no Input Device. But I can connect Bluetooth headphones. Then I have sound on them.

Before, There was Windows on the EZbook and there the sound worked fine.

I have already tried:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

install instead -i ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso --atom

install instead -i ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso --apollo

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Using alsamixer to configure soundcard. When starting received:

(solved it later, but don't remember how. Could configure the soundcard and adjust volume values, but still no sound)

```
alsamixer
ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5701:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib control.c:1528:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL default
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
```

When starting up the computer shows this error, but there is no SGX option in Bios:

```
[0.324064] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
/dev/sda2: clean,.158898/15597568 files, 3460959/62383360 blocks
[8.468418] sof-audio-pci-intel-apl 0000:00:0e.0: error: tplg request firmware intel/sof-tplg/sof-g1K-es8336-ssp2.tplg failed err -2 
[8.468467] sof-audio-pci-intel-ap1 0000:00:0e.0: you may need to download the firmware from https://github.comithesofprojectisof-bin/
[8.468500] sof-audio-pci-intel-apl 0000:00:0e.0: error: failed to load DSP topology -2 
[8.468523] sof-audio-pci-intel-apl 0000:00:0e.0: ASoC: error at snd_soc_component_probe on 0000:00:0e.0: -2 
[8.468587] sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: ASoC: failed to instantiate card -2 
[8.468702] sof-essx8336 sof-essx8336: snd_soc_register_card failed: -2
```

Nothing solved the sound problem yet. Additional information:

```
lspci | grep -i audio
00:0e.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High Definition Audio (rev 06)

inxi -SMA
    System:
  Host: nameless-EZbook Kernel: 5.19.0-32-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME v: 42.5 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Jumper product: EZbook v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Jumper model: N/A serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends v: GN10BV106 date: 08/11/2021
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High Definition Audio
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-apl
  API: ALSA v: k5.19.0-32-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 status: active
```

Comment: For any hardware built around the infamous Atom CPUs, this contains optimizations and better hardware support: https://www.linuxium.com.au/isos

Comment: Tried two systems from linuxium.com.au/isos. Didn't solve the sound problem

Answer (score 0):

The sound works from kernel version 5.16. very good.
I installed the kernel via the "Mainline Tool" and after a system reboot, configured the audio via the Alsamixer.
Please be careful. Modifications to the current kernel can destroy your system.
Be sure to make a backup. (no backup, no pity)

Comment: I tried to do this. Kernel was above version 5.16.  I installed a newer Ubuntu version so I didn't need to use "Mainline Tool".  When using alsamixer, I encountered errors. But I solved them and could select the right sound in alsamixer and could adjust the sound values but there was still no sound.